# GCE Instances Network connection speeds on internal network

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine

Coming from a background of vSphere vm's with vNIC's defined on creation as I am do the GCE instances internal and public ip network connections use a particular virtualised NIC and if so what speed is it 100Mbit/s 1Gb or 10Gb?

I'm not so much interested in the bandwidth from the public internet in but more what kind of connection is possible between instances given networks can span regions

Is it right to think of a GCE project network as a logical 100Mbit/s 1Gb or 10Gb network spanning the atlantic I plug my instances into or should there be no minimum expectation because too many variables exist like noisy neighbours and inter region bandwidth not to mention physical distance?

Answer (score 2):

The virtual network adapter advertised in GCE conforms to the virtio-net specification (specifically [virtio-net 0.9.5](http://ozlabs.org/~rusty/virtio-spec/virtio-0.9.5.pdf) with multiqueue). Within the same zone we offer up to [2Gbps/core](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#egress_throughput_caps) of network throughput. The NIC itself does not advertise a specific speed. Performance between zones and between regions is subject to capacity limits and quality-of-service within Google's WAN.

The performance relevant features advertised by our virtual NIC as of December 2015 are support for:

- IPv4 TCP Transport Segmentation Offload
- IPv4 TCP Large Receive Offload
- IPv4 TCP/UDP Tx checksum calculation offload
- IPv4 TCP/UDP Rx checksum verification offload
- Event based queue signaling/interrupt suppression.

In our testing for best performance it is advantageous to enable of all of these features. Images supplied by Google will take advantage of all the features available in the shipping kernel (that is, some images ship with older kernels for stability and may not be able to take advantage of all of these features).

Answer (score 1):

I can see up to 1Gb/s between instances within the same zone, but AFAIK that is not something which is guaranteed, especially for tansatlantic communication. Things might change in the future, so I'd suggest to follow official product announcements.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few enhancements in the years since the original question and answers were posted.  In particular, the "2Gbps/core" (really, per vCPU) is still there but there is now a minimum cap of 10 Gbps for VMs with two or more vCPUs. The maximum cap is currently 32 Gbps, with 50 Gbps and 100 Gbps caps in the works.

The per-VM egress caps remain "guaranteed not to exceed" not "guaranteed to achieve."

In terms of achieving peak, trans-Atlantic performance, one suggestion would be the same as for any high-latency path.  Ensure that your sources and destinations are tuned to allow sufficient TCP window to achieve the throughput you desire.  In particular, this formula would be in effect:

Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime

Of course that too is a "guaranteed not to exceed" rather than a "guaranteed to achieve" thing.  As was stated before "Performance between zones and between regions is subject to capacity limits and quality-of-service within Google's WAN."